# For loop in jQuery. How to?

Tags: jquery

How can I replace this for-each loop with jQuery?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    hidebutton = $("#hideall");
    hidebutton.click(function(){
        for(i=1;i<=6;i++){
                var countrylist = document.getElementById("Country-"+i);
                countrylist.style.display = "none";
            }
    });
});
```

The HTML is

```
<input id="hideall" type="button" value='Hide Countries' /><br /><br />
<div id="Country-1">USA</div>
<div id="Country-2">UK</div>
<div id="Country-3">UAE</div>
<div id="Country-4">China</div>
<div id="Country-5">India</div>
<div id="Country-6">Japan</div>
```

Comment: You forgot a `var` for `hideButton`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited your jsfiddle, added an example of jQuery foreach in a comment.  However, you don't need foreach here because jQuery can operate on a collection.  I changed your HTML as well, you need to group those divs better:

```
<div id="Countries">
    <div id="Country-1">USA</div>
    <div id="Country-2">UK</div>
    <div id="Country-3">UAE</div>
    <div id="Country-4">China</div>
    <div id="Country-5">India</div>
    <div id="Country-6">Japan</div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    hidebutton = $("#hideall");
    hidebutton.click(function(){
        $('#Countries div').hide();
        // $('#Countries div').each(function(index, divElement) { ... });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nLfNj/3/

Comment: You should post your solution here instead of describing code you added to another site.

Comment: jsfiddle is common on SO and public so anyone can see the solution.  The question included a jsfiddle so I thought it fitting that the answer should as well.  Furthermore, I happen to prefer a fiddle to code I can't execute.  Readers can just jump in and try it.  Is there any particular reason you mind clicking on an extra link to see the solution?

Comment: The main reason is that StackOverflow is meant to be a standalone repository of questions and answers, and should not rely on the uptime or general availability of another site. It is simply how StackOverflow works. jsFiddle is extremely useful, and linking to it is a great idea. But there have been times where jsFiddle has been down, and answers given been rendered useless. Please help maintain the integrity of this site by primarily answering here, and then augmenting your answer with external links if you desire. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

### There's a CSS3 selector for your needs

As you may know jQuery supports CSS3 selectors whether browser does or doesn't. Hence you can use a more advanced selector that will select all elements with ID starting with `Country`:

```
$('div[id^="Country"]').hide();
```

Comment: if $container = "#countrydiv" then, container.[id^="Country"].hide() is not working. i guess i made a mess in the syntax.

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
hidebutton.click(function(){
    $('[id^="Country-"]').hide();
});
```

Note that will also hide any elements that happen to start with "Country-" that you don't want to hide, but assuming you don't have any of those, this will work.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a class to each of the elements (eg, `class="Country"`), then write

```
$('.Country').hide();
```

Comment: Ya, adding the classname is the simplest way to do it. but if this is not the solution, then how to do it?. This may not required but i am keen to know the for loop conversion in jquery since i am a novice :)

Comment: @user: You can use an attribute selector: `$('div[id^="Country"]')`  http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 0):

give each country a class (i.e. "country"), then do `$('.country').hide()`

Comment: Ya, adding the classname is the simplest way to do it. but if this is not the solution, then how to do it?. This may not required but i am keen to know the for loop conversion in jquery since i am a novice :)